# Is this word choice possible?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning

I know it's possible to say **'we are in the same class together'** but is it also possible to say **'we go to the same class together'**? I've tried looking on here: https://www.englishforums.com/English/GoInToTheSameClass/bvhvkk/post.htm  but the answers were ambiguous and I'm looking for something more subtle.

> 1. We are in the same class.
> 2. We go to the same class.

Also, if the later is possible, do we say "*go **to** the same class*" or "*go **in** the same class"?*

Comment: Thanks for asking a question and welcome to ELL. If you tell us where you found the answers you think are ambiguous, and tell us why you think so, we might be able provide a more useful answer.

Comment: I found them on another forum and I think they were ambiguous because they didn't clearly state if it's possible to use go or not and focused more on which preposition is correct and why thus I'm still not sure whether they were speaking theoretically which preposition WOULD be paired with 'go' if said word-choice was correct and possible or whether it acutually is correct and possible and the choice of a preposition is the real problem here.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this forum? Use the grey `edit` link under your question.

Comment: That question is about the use of the phrase _me and my friend._ _We are in the same class_ means either _We will graduate in the same year_ or _We sit in the same room with the same instructor._ _We go to the same class_ means **only** _We sit in the same room with the same instructor._ _We go in the same class_ is meaningless in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are in the same class

means you both are in the same "group" or "cohort" of *something*, it could be:

> 1) the same academic class, e.g. the Class of 2016
>   2) the same subject class, e.g. Introductory Chemistry
>   3) the same social status, e.g. aristocratic class
>   4) the same passenger class, e.g. First Class

by adding "together", it will tend to bias the meaning towards the first two possibilities.

> we are in the same class together

would probably be understood to mean the same subject class, e.g. Astronomy.

> We go to the same class.

usually means you both are physically in the same classroom taking the same subject class.

A more usual phrasing to express sharing the same subject class might be

> We ***take*** the same Physics class.
>   We ***have*** the same Physics class.

Comment: Another possible verb would be _attend_. _We attend the same class_